# Doctrine migrations and data transformation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine's Migrations in my symfony 2 project to safely migrate my database. Most of the times it's all about adding columns, but sometimes I split columns (because of normalization) or I change releationships (one to one -> one to many).

The creation itself is simple. But deleting or renaming the old column/property is not. This can and may only happen if the data is transformed from the old format to the new one.

### Example:

Current situation: Task entity with one tag

Future situation: Task entity with one to many Tags

I tried the preUp/postUp functions in the migration script. 
Pseudo-code:

`Fetch Tasks
Foreach Tasks as Task
$tag = new Tag();
$tag->setName($task->getTag());
persist
$task->setNewtag($tag);
persist
flush`

In the second migration script I can safely delete the old Tag column and rename Newtag to Tag.

### Problem:

When I --dry-run the script, the SQL commands are not executed (ofcourse) but the 'transformation' scripts are, whith an error as result because the columns does not exist.

How can I overcome this error? Can I intercept the result of the SQL-script and only execute the transformation if SQL result = true?

Comment: Found this:
https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/124
I personally would never modify objects in a migration. I've always written "migration" scripts (as symfony2 commands) for that as data transformation should be a very carefully monitored operation, and a one time event at that.

Comment: If there's no business logic associated to the change in the relationship, you can probably do it safely with another SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, I have found that GitHub issue too. But I don't see how I can achieve this without using the Entity Manager. The former workflow I've used was to write migrations in commands too, but I thought it could be made easier by packing it into the Doctrine Migration process so the correct sequence is forced.